# operator '<' declared in type 'XXX' must be 'static'

Tags: swift

I have the following implementation and also added Comparable extension as follows. But I am getting the following error. I wonder how I could able to fix it.

> error: operator '<' declared in type 'Item' must be 'static'
>       func < (lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
>            ^
>       static

```
class Item
{
    var timeStamp : Date
    var value : Int

    init(_ value: Int)
    {
      self.value = value
      self.timeStamp = Date()
    }
}

extension Item: Comparable
{
    func < (lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
        return lhs.timeStamp < rhs.timeStamp
    }

    func == (lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
        return lhs.timeStamp == rhs.timeStamp
    }
}
```

Comment: So...add `static` to it?

Comment: Actually Xcode presents a Fix-it to insert the static keyword: Click on the small red circle and then on “Fix”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Comparable` protocol requires that the `<` operator implementation is static. It is documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/comparable/1538311). You could fix your code by adding the `static` keyword like so:

```swift
static func < (lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
     return lhs.timeStamp < rhs.timeStamp
}
```